# Jqgrid: how to pass arguments to edit url webmethood

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                            url: 'UserRoles.aspx/GetUserRoles',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            mtype: 'POST',
                            colNames: ["User Role Id", "User Role", "Description", "Status"],
                            colModel: [
                                { name: 'UserRoleId', index: 'UserRoleId', jsonmap: 'UserRoleId', width: 75 },
                                { name: 'UserRoleName', index: 'UserRoleName', jsonmap: 'UserRoleName', width: 150, editable: true },
                                { name: 'UserRoleDescription', index: 'UserRoleDescription', jsonmap: 'UserRoleDescription', formatter: 'textarea', width: 150, editable: true },
                                { name: 'UserRoleStatus', index: 'UserRoleStatus', jsonmap: 'UserRoleStatus', formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', width: 150, editable: true }
                            ],
                            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                                // extend the parameter which will be send to the server
                                //postData.formVars = $("#Content2").serializeArray();
                                // serialize the parameters as JSON string
                                return JSON.stringify(postData);
                            },
                            caption: "User Roles List",
                            viewrecords: true,
                            gridview: true,
                            autoencode: true,
                            loadonce: true,
                            loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
                                alert("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + err);
                                //jQuery("#rsperror").html("Type: "+st+"; Response: "+ xhr.status + " "+xhr.statusText);
                            },
                            jsonReader: {
                                root: function (obj) { return obj.d; }, //array containing actual data
                                //page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                                //total: function (obj) { return obj.d.length/25; },
                                //records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; }, //total number of records
                                repeatitems: false,
                                id: 'UserRoleId',
                                cell: '',
                            },
                            width: 780,
                            height: 250,
                            rowNum: 25,
                            rowList: [25, 50, 100],
                            pager: "#jqGridPager",

                        }).navGrid('#jqGridPager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, excel: true, addtext: 'ADD' }, // Edit options 
                        {
                            savekey: [true, 13],
                            reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                            jqModal: false,
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            closeAfterEdit: true,
                            url: '../BibLOSApp/UserRoles.aspx/UpdateUserRole',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            mtype:'POST',
                            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                            serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                                // extend the parameter which will be send to the server
                                //postData.formVars = $("#Content2").serializeArray();
                                // serialize the parameters as JSON string
                                alert(JSON.stringify(postData));

                                return JSON.stringify(postData);

                            },

                        });

                    });

                </script>


code behind

[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string UpdateUserRole()
        {
            string s = "test";
            return s;
        }
```

I am able to load the grid but the issue is while editing the data. I am able to just invoke the method when i click on submit while editing. could some help me on how to get the json data from the jqgrid to the webmethod.

Comment: You need to have  json data as input param in webmethod. Currently UpdateUserRole dont have an input param

Comment: Do you have problems in Add, Edit or both? Your current options are applied on Edit only. Why you don't use `postData.formVars = $("#Content2").serializeArray();` (see commented lines)? You neede to add `id`, `formVars ` and the names all editable columns as parameters of `UpdateUserRole` method. Do you verified with respect of Developer Tools (press F12 in web browser to start) that HTTP traffic contains request to the server?

Comment: @qamar I am able to invoke method without param. Could please explain how to pass the params

Comment: @Oleg actually I am not clear abt postData.formVars = $("#Content2").serializeArray();  syntax so commented. Could please give the syntax for formvars

Comment: Do you tried to add standard parameters like `string id, string UserRoleName, string UserRoleDescription, string UserRoleStatus` to `UpdateUserRole` function? Do you get the parameters in your server code? What parameters exactly you need? If you have `$("#Content2")` form and you want to post it then `postData.formVars = $("#Content2").serializeArray();` would be correct, but I don't know **what additional parameters you need to send**.

Comment: @Oleg I tried adding parameters for UpdateUserRole and i am getiing internal server error 500, the method is not invoked. i have added formVars and it is working but the problem is i am not able to get the data in webmethod UpdateUserRole

Comment: I recommend you to use Developer Tools of Chrome/Internet Explorer/Firefox to *trace HTTP traffic*. I personally use mostly free [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) tool. If you have full trace of HTTP requests and responses you can verify what is wrong (response, the type of parameters of `UpdateUserRole`, missing parameter which can't be Null, ...). So you would be understand *the reason* or internal server error 500 and will be able to fix it.

Comment: @Oleg I checked in Firefox without any arguments in UpdateUserRole method(POST) and found that the json data is in Request Payload under params but i dont know how to use that in my webmethod `{"UserRoleName":"Uer Profile 7","UserRoleDescription":"test description.","UserRoleStatus":"Yes","oper":"edit","id":"7"}`. when i use mtype as GET, i can see the same json data in querystring and can get the data using HttpContext. But i still want to know how to get the values in parameters. Please help me here

Comment: I finally found the issue, i didnt pass all the parameter names same as my return object. I chnaged it and it is working. thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I recommend you to continue to use Developer Tools and analyze HTTP traffic in the future. In my opinion it simplifies finding the errors. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string UpdateUserRole(string UserRoleName, string UserRoleDescription, string UserRoleStatus, string id)
    {
        string s = "test";
        return s;
    }
```

I have deleted oper paramter from my json object and passed rest of the parameters and it worked.

Comment: You can need to include all parameters which jqGrid send to you. It's important just if you do have some parameter like `string UserRoleName` then **every HTTP request** to the server have to contain the parameter (at least with empty value). The error in your previous attempts was: you used wrong name of input parameters, jqGrid didn't send the parameter with the name and ASP.NET returned internal server error 500 in the case.